# How to make a WebviewRenderer IOS external url access?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I did an IOS webviewrenderer and I can not access an external url like google's, how can I do that?

I'm following the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";
    WKUserContentController userController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (Control == null) {
            userController = new WKUserContentController ();
            var script = new WKUserScript (new NSString (JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
            userController.AddUserScript (script);
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "invokeAction");

            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);
            SetNativeControl (webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts ();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler ("invokeAction");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup ();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            var uri = e.NewElement.Uri.ToString();
            Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(uri, false)));
        }
    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code you are showing is definitely not C. Did you mean to tag C# instead?

Comment: Yes, but when I mark C # it changes to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different with load local html file.If you want to access a remote URL like google .You don't need to set the Parameter `isDir` .

```
if (e.NewElement != null) 
{
  var uri = e.NewElement.Uri.ToString();
  Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(uri)));
}
```